# can't get Java import to work

Tags: java, jdom

I am trying to read and write modifications to an XML file. After much research I selected the JDOM approach for this activity. I'm not doing big files and I just need something quick and simple. I downloaded the JDOM project files from jdom.org/downloads/docs.html. I also downloaded some exmple files that show the read write code using JDOM. Piece of cake Right?

Wrong. I have screwed around for several weeks trying to get my Java JDOM project to work. Using Eclipse on Windows 7 PC. I can not get the import statements to actually import the required JDOM items.

I have my project files in S:\Java\procXML folder. The source files are in the S:\Java\procXML\src\procXML folder.

The JDOM files in my S:\Java\JDOM folder. The JDOM java source files are in the S:\Java\JDOM\core\src\java\org\jdom2 folder.

I have the CLASSPATH set to S:\Java\JDOM\core\src\java.

I get an error message from Eclipse saying the org.jdom2 imports cannot be resolved.

The import section of the procXMLfile is as follows:

```
package procXML;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

public class procXMLfile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
      File xmlFile = new File("c:\\file.xml");
```

This stuff should be simple. The reason I'm using java is because I need to write some programs for MAC and Android and Java can be compiled for all of those platforms. I'm about ready to get rid of java and go with so other language, so I'm hoping someone can tell me what is wrong.

Comment: have you tried compiling it without Eclipse using the command line? Chances are, you need to add the S:\Java\JDOM\core\src\java\org\jdom2 folder to your build path.  You should probably build the JDOM2 library first and reference the .jar instead of the source files.

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of imports to avoid doing all of the stuff you recommend? Won't I have to us import statements if I want to use elements of a .jar file

Comment: you need to package your JDOM in a jar and try to use that in your source code via pom etc... or add it in your classpath

Comment: @BillHay Import statements tell the class what to import.  It doesn't tell Eclipse/java where to import the files from.  I would recommend doing an introductory Java course online.  You're going to run into these problems with any language if you don't understand how some basics work.

Comment: @BillHay JDOM is easier to use than vtd-xml (disclaimer, I am the author of JDOM) ;-) .....

Comment: To vtd-xml-author and rolfi. These kinds of responses really aggravate me. If you don't know how to answer my question please go somewhere else. The correct response is given by Pierre-Jean below

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a source folder in your `CLASSPATH`.
Java classpath doesn't know how to interpret your source project.

You could compile your code through javac or via Eclipse to get a JAR file.

But if you just want to use JDOM in your project (which seems to be the case here), the simplest way is to add already packaged jar to your `CLASSPATH`:

- Download the [latest binaries from JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/dist/binary/jdom-2.0.6.zip)
- Unzip them in a folder, for instance `S:\Java\procXML\lib`
- Add in your classpath the jar inside the lib folders: `S:\Java\procXML\lib\jdom-2.0.6.jar`,`S:\Java\procXML\lib\lib\jaxen-1.1.6.jar`, `S:\Java\procXML\lib\lib\xercesImpl.jar`, `S:\Java\procXML\lib\lib\xml-apis.jar`, `S:\Java\procXML\lib\lib\xalan\serializer-2.7.2.jar`, `S:\Java\procXML\lib\lib\xalan\xalan-2.7.2.jar`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I did change the classpath as you suggested. I also added those jar files to my eclipse project. The project is now working.